# INotifyPropertyChanged not notifying datatrigger

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button in windowA which opens a windowB and changes style to show that windowB is open. When I close the windowB I want to change the button style back. Both the windows use the same view model.

In the view model I use INotifyPropertyChanged to detect a property IsWindowBOpen and use it to change the button style as follows:

```
<ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWindowBOpen}" Value="True">
    <ei:GoToStateAction TargetName="myButton" StateName="IsOpen"/>
</ei:DataTrigger>
<ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWindowBOpen}" Value="False">
    <ei:GoToStateAction TargetName="myButton" StateName="IsClose"/>
</ei:DataTrigger>
```

When opening WindowB, I change the property IsWindowBOpen to true in the view model. The property change event fires showing true and the data trigger applies.

When I close WindowB, I change the property IsWindowBOpen to false in the view model. The property change event fires showing false but the data trigger never applies.

I've read fairly extensively but can't seem to find anything logically wrong with this approach?

@Warlock

In the View Model:

```
private bool _isWindowBOpen;

    public bool IsWindowBOpen
    {
        get { return _isWindowBOpen}
        set
        {
            _isWindowBOpen = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsWindowBOpen");
        }
    }

private void DoClose(object param)
    {

        switch (type)
        {
            case "WindowB":
                IsWindowBOpen = false;
                break;

        }

        main.Items.Remove(windowB);
    }

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var test = IsWindowBOpen; //Gets set to True/False accordingly
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible spelling mistakes. Please check, that the SateName "IsClose" is a valid name.

Comment: Yeah was example syntax but I've checked and it is correct.

Comment: Could you please provide code that handle a WindowB closing.

Answer (score 1):

Prepare the firing squad :(

On creating windowB and binding it to the 'same' view model, I was instantiating a new instance.

```
public WindowBView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new WindowABViewModel();
    }
```

Instead of using the existing one.

I apologise for wasting everyones time. Single shot to the heart please.

Comment: It was quite interesting, because tricks with Modal Windows is a weakness of MVVM.

Comment: When something seems oddly wrong with your code, it means you're doing something dumb.